# Methods for Python classes representation

Tags: python, class, instance, representation

I know that methods `__repr__` and `__str__` exist to give a formal and informal representation of class instances. But does an equivalent exist for class objects too, so that when the class object is printed, a nice representation of it could be shown?

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "instance of class Foo"
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> print foo
instance of class Foo
>>> print Foo
__main__.Foo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `print(foo)`, `foo`'s `__str__` method is called. `__str__` is found in the class of `foo`, which is `Foo`.

Similarly, when you call `print(Foo)`, `Foo`'s `__str__` method is called. `__str__` is found in the class of `Foo`, which is normally `type`. You can change that using a metaclass:

```
class FooType(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return 'Me a Foo'
    def __repr__(cls):
        return '<Foo>'

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__=FooType
    def __str__(self):
        return "instance of class Foo"

print(Foo)
# Me a Foo

print(repr(Foo))
# <Foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with a metaclass, but AFAIK, there's no general solution for normal classes.

If it's just your own classes, you could adopt a coding standard of including a particular class variable with your metadata, ie:

```
class Whatever(object):
    classAuthor = "me"
    classCreated = "now"
```

Or if you're using a python that supports class decorators, you could use a decorator to annotate it for you automatically or enforce that the metadata is there.

But... **maybe you just want `AClass.__name__` ?**

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it's a good thing that you can't make a custom `repr` string for classes; the point of a class is to create instances of that class.

Comment: In some situations it can be useful imho. For example if you want to print a list of classes and provide for them custom descriptions instead of their full name.

Comment: In that case you should use `str` instead of `repr`. It's not necessary but often nice to have the latter be the actual Python source code representation of the value so that `eval(repr(x)) == x`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `__repr__` or `__str__` on the class type but you can use the [docstring](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) to present information about the class

```
>>> class Foo:
...     """Foo's description"""
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "instance of class Foo"
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> print foo
instance of class Foo
>>> print Foo.__doc__
Foo's description
>>> Foo.__doc__
"Foo's description"
```