# Python 3.x : how to get a representation of a class that return a float?

Tags: python, string, class, presentation

I have a class that return a float number, and I want to print it in the `__main__` as a representation of the previous class, formatted to trim some numbers over floating point. If I override the `__str__` method I obviously get `TypeError` exception, as the following example:

```
class override_str:
    def __str__(self):
        return(77.543)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print("float got by overriden __str__  : {:2f}".format(override_str()))
```

So, how can I "fix"? Using the `__repr__` doesn't seem to help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Methods for Python classes representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086113/methods-for-python-classes-representation)

Comment: Do you have to be able to format the float value in the `str.format()` template?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the [`__format__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) to customise how your custom class is interpolated into a string format:

```
class SpecialFormat:
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if format_spec.endswith('f'):
            return format(77.543, format_spec)
        return 'Unknown format'
```

This delegates to the [`format()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) to handle the actual formatting, but it gives you a hook to determine what format is being requested for your custom object.

The `__format__` method is passed the full [Format Specification Mini Language string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). Like `__str__` you still need to return a string object.

Demo:

```
>>> 'Formatted as float: {:.2f}'.format(SpecialFormat())
'Formatted as float: 77.54'
>>> 'Formatted as float: {}'.format(SpecialFormat())
'Formatted as float: Unknown format'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the float to a string within the `__str__` method before returning it.

```
class my_str:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(77.543)

>>> a = my_str()
>>> a
<__main__.my_str instance at 0x02783288>   # a is an instance of my_str

>>> print a    # calls the __str__ method
77.543
```